# Trigger select event of jquery datepicker on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, handlebars.js

I have html as :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="activityDate" name="activityDate" value="
{{getDateEditAct date}}" ">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="deadlineForConfirmation" 
name="deadlineForConfirmation" >
```

and I want to trigger select event of jquery datepicker of `activityDate` on page load so the this fucntion will be called :

```
  $('#activityDate').datepicker({
            maxDate: tripdep,
            minDate: minimumDate,
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
              $('#deadlineForConfirmation').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate       || tripdep);
            }
     });
```

and the maxDate of `deadlineForConfirmation` will be set automatically.

I am trying to trigger this by :-

`$('#activityDate').select();`

or

`$('#activityDate').change();`

But its not working. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as follows . Specify the date you want

```
  $('#activityDate').datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9EwYG/)**